# Setting the innerHTML of a div to information retrieved from a MySQL database (using AJAX/PHP)?

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax

On my page (index.php), I have a content-editable div with id = "name" and a content-editable div with id = "info".  I also have a button with id = "save" and a button with id = "lookUp".

in **index.php**:

```
<p> <div> Name: </div> <div id="name" contenteditable="true"> </div> </p>
<p> <div> Info: </div> <div id="info" contenteditable="true"> </div> </p>

<p>
    <button id="save" type="button" style="float: left;" class="buttonText"> Save </button>
    <button id="lookUp" type="button" style="float: left;" class="buttonText"> Look Up </button>
</p>
```

I would like the page to be able to do two things:

*1)*  If the user clicks the 'Save' button and both content-editable divs are filled, the name and info entered into the content-editable divs by the user are saved to a two-column table (columns: "name" and "info") in a local MySQL database. *I have already implemented this functionality* with AJAX/PHP, and it works without error.

*2)*  If the user clicks the 'Look Up' button, then I would like the text entered into the content-editable div with id = "name" (the innerHTML of the name div) to be looked up in the database.  If the name is found, I would like the site to retrieve the text stored in the corresponding entry's 'info' column and enter it into the content-editable div with id = "info" (set the innerHTML of the 'info' div to the retrieved info).

So far I have partially implemented *2)* with the following code:

in **index.php**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(argument) 
    {
        $('#lookUp').click(function()
        {
            $name = $('#name').html();
            $info = $('#info').html();

            $.ajax(
            {
              url: 'lookup.php', type: 'post', data: {nameSubmit: $name}, datatype: 'html', success: function(rsp){alert(rsp);}
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

in **lookup.php**:

```
<?php 

    $name = $_POST['nameSubmit'];
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);

    $connect = mysql_connect( "localhost", "localUserName", "localPassword", "" );
    $selectedDB = mysql_select_db("nameInfoDatabase", $connect);

    $lookup = "SELECT * FROM nameInfoTable";
    $lookupResults = mysql_query( $lookup, $connect );

    $nameFound = FALSE;

    while($record = mysql_fetch_array($lookupResults))
    {
        if( $record['name'] == $name )
        {
            $nameFound = TRUE;
            $info = $record['info'];
        }
    }   

    if( $nameFound ){ echo "Account Located.  Info: " . $info; }
    else{ echo "FAILURE: Name not found!"; }

    // NOW WHAT?
?>
```

After a "Look Up" button-click, the information I want to be saved to the innerHTML of the div with id = "info" in index.php is saved to the variable $info in lookup.php.  This $info is correctly printed (echoed) to the dialogue pop-up, but I want it to be entered into the content-editable, id = "info" div of the index.php page.  How do I proceed?

I have tried things like echoing lines of javascipt, as is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164130/how-to-output-javascript-with-php) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287357/access-php-variable-in-javascript), but I have not been able to get it working with existing StackOverflow Q&As.  I am sorry if this question is overly basic or has already been addressed in a way that I did not understand, I am very new to PHP and back-end development.

Thanks for the help!  Jack

Comment: `SELECT *` form table and then check for the name in the loop is so  excessive. Use `SELECT * FROM nameInfoTable WHERE name='".$name."' LIMIT 1` instead and check if [mysql_num_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) == 1

Answer (score 0):

To properly use this data with JS you can send it in native JSON format.
**lookup.php**

```
<?php
// here connection and escaping stuff
$lookup = "SELECT * FROM nameInfoTable WHERE name='".$name."' LIMIT 1";
$lookupResults = mysql_query( $lookup, $connect );
// no $nameFound or while loop needed
if (mysql_num_rows($lookupResults) == 1) { // one result obtained
    echo json_encode(mysql_fetch_array($lookupResults)); // fetch and send
}
else {
    // you can do nothing, just don't send anything and response will be empty
    // that's how you can understand that "name" was not found
}
?>
```

in index.php improve youк ajax success function:

```
success: function (rsp) {
    if (rsp) { // if data not empty
        var data = JSON.parse(rsp); // parse recieved data 
        $('#info').html(data.info); // properties' names are exactly as columns in your table or like query aliases
    }
}
```

**EDIT** Some suggestions that don't really answer your question but may be helpful

1. Try to use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead of mysql. It's already deprecated and
   this a good start to learn object oriented syntax
2. You're escaping post var - it's very good, but you don't check
   whether it exists neither on client-side `(if ($name) { // do ajax request })` nor on back-end `if (!empty($_POST['nameSubmit'])) { // do all other stuff }`
3. I don't think you need so much variables, also some coders prefer another
   style of preparing queries.
4. Actually you need only `info` from your table, not all `*`

I'll try to show this all in one piece of code:

```
if (!empty($_POST['nameSubmit'])) { // check post variable
    // establish connection
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "localUserName", "localPassword", "nameInfoDatabase");
    // prepare query, sprintf is a little bit easier to read 
    $query = sprintf("SELECT info FROM nameInfoTable WHERE name='%s' LIMIT 1", mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nameSubmit']));
    // query, actually you can put sprintf here
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
    // result will have 0 or 1 in property here
    if ($result->num_rows) {
        // php Array("info"=>"...") will be converted to {"info": "..."} for JS
        echo jscon_encode($result->fetch_assoc());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this was very helpful.  Do I need to make changes to the data: or datatype: part of my AJAX request to let it know I'm sending back some stuff via json?

Comment: no, your `data` (what you sending) should be still `{nameSubmit: $name}`. `dataType: "json"` is not really needed here, cause (as [spec says](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)) it has _Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html)_ of data returned. Also, in your case, if you specify `dataType: "json"` your server side script **must** return `null` or `{}` (empty object) otherwise it will be _also rejected_, so you **must** `json_encode` at least empty array. So, no, better remove `dataType` and leave `data` as is

Comment: It seems that everything is functions as it should until myAJAX success function.  Oddly, I am getting the error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token A ... ( index ) : 2" - odd because my AJAX success function is in my index.php file well below line 2... in fact, line 2 is empty and does not run an error when the page loads.