# Embed a javascript variable into my html anchor href

Tags: javascript, html

I have a piece of HTML which should look something like the following when rendered by the browser:

```
<b>This is a test</b><a href="foo.php?bar=yay">Test over!</a>
```

The problem I have is that `foo.php` is defined in a javascript var in the document. For argument sake, the name of the var is `myPath`. I'm trying to figure out how to get rid of the hard coded `foo.php` from the HTML above and have it read it from `myPath` instead.

I've tried different variations of escaping quotes and `document.write()` but haven't had much luck.

Is there a way to do something similar to:

`<a href=" + myPath + "?bar=yay">`

and have it render `foo.php` from `myPath`?

Comment: look for javascript or jquery for DOM manipulation. so after page is rendered, you can modify href of the hyperlink or insert the hyperlink in it's parent node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give your link an `ID`, you can use that in your JavaScript to reference the element and modify its `href`.

```
<a href="#" id="js_link">
```

And then your JavaScript could look something like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var myPath = 'foo.php',
        link = document.getElementById('js_link');

    link.href = myPath;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `getElementByID` then set the href property.

Check out this **[working example](http://jsfiddle.net/seadonk/hk9zkfLr/)**.

```
(function () {
    var a = document.getElementById('mylink');
    var fooLink = 'foo.php';
    var link = fooLink + '?bar=yay';
    a.href = link;
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use inline script to output your javascript variable.
This might help [How to output JavaScript with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164130/how-to-output-javascript-with-php)