# Notification with alert

Tags: php, jquery, alert

I am trying to notify the user for their expired products. This works well. but i am not being able to display the product name in alert which is the variable `$product->name`.

```
   <?php foreach($productsofuser as $product):?>
        <?php if($product->status="Expired")
            {
                ?><script>alert('Product expired!');</script><?php
            }
        ?>
    <?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: this link will probably help you - http://stackoverflow.com/a/1164353/4606122

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to output JavaScript with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164130/how-to-output-javascript-with-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the product name to the string:

```
  <?php foreach($productsofuser as $product):?>
        <?php if($product->status="Expired")
            {
                ?><script>alert('Product <?php echo $product->name; ?> expired!');</script><?php
            }
        ?>
    <?php endforeach;?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `echo`

```html
<?php foreach($productsofuser as $product):?>
        <?php if($product->status="Expired")
            {
               echo"<script>alert('Product expired!');</script>";
            }
        ?>
    <?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: I.m trying to display product name too.

Comment: This produces exactly the same output as the original question.