# Is there any thing I am missing here? or better way?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to save Session variable in index.php page and to access in I_detail.php.

The following piece of code working fine.

index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function loadpage(a)
            {
                //var b = a;
                <?php 
                    $_SESSION['$p_id'] = 'asdfasdfasfd';  //this is working
                ?>
                    document.location.href='I_detail.php';
            }
</script>
```

### I_detail.php

```
<?php 
    echo("{$_SESSION['$p_id']}"."<br />");

?>
```

The problem I am getting that as I changed value of JavaScript variable into session variable like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadpage(a)
{
var b = a;
<?php 
$_SESSION['$p_id'] = '<script>document.write(b)</script>';  //this is working not working
?>
   document.location.href='I_detail.php';
}
</script>
```

I tried solution in mentioned in the following doc but somehow still facing no output.
[JavaScript to PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164130/how-to-output-javascript-with-php)

Is there anything am i missing? or any better way to do this?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're trying to achieve, however writing PHP in to JS is very rarely a good approach. If you could provide details of your goal, then we can offer solutions which follow best practices.

Comment: Maybe it could help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming

Comment: Just got answer and really worked. Beside that, do you guys think this is un-save approach? Damn sure this question may asked many times and I researched too, may be new learner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly pass variables from JavaScript to PHP in the way you've attempted because the PHP code has already been processed by the time your JavaScript code runs.
Modify the loadpage function to pass the value via the URL as a query parameter, and then read this parameter in your PHP script.

index.php :

```
function loadpage(a) {
    // Redirect to I_detail.php with a query parameter
    document.location.href = 'I_detail.php?p_id=' + encodeURIComponent(a);
}
```

I_detail.php:

```
<?php
session_start(); // Ensure session is started

// Check if the p_id parameter exists
if (isset($_GET['p_id'])) {
    $_SESSION['$p_id'] = $_GET['p_id'];
}

// Use the session variable
echo(isset($_SESSION['$p_id']) ? $_SESSION['$p_id'] : "No p_id set") . "<br />";
?>
```